# Need a translation toolkit that supports msgctxt

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress 3.1 came out recently with a lot of new features, and as I can see, there's a big change in support for translation. The context feature of GNU Gettext (**msgctxt**) is now used a lot in Wordpress's code, some *e() and _*() are replaced by _x() and _ex(). And... it's causing a problem for me.
I'm using PoEdit to edit the translation for Wordpress, but currently it doesn't support msgctxt. I know how to manually edit the .po file to translate a string that uses msgctxt, but it's a hard work. And, the bigger problem is that when I use PoEdit's Update button, all my hard works... go away, the things that I changed by manually editing the .po file go away!
So now, I come here to ask you, do you know any translation toolkit (like PoEdit) that supports GNU gettext's **msgctxt**? Please tell me, thanks a lot for your help :D

Answer (score 2):

Great news: PoEdit 1.5.5 now supports msgctxt!  The key thing to get right is the keyword sources configuration within your Catalog properties.  For _x and _ex it should look like: "_x:1,2c" and "_ex:1,2c".  Covered in more detail here: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/translating-your-theme/

Answer (score 1):

you can use PoEditor.com it supports the msgctxt!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a year-old question, but have you tried Automattic's own [GlotPress](http://glotpress.trac.wordpress.org/)?

It's still a work in progress, and you have to install it from the Subversion repository, but it does support translation contexts and it allows collaboration.